# SQL report server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SQL EXPRESS database already running.
I have created a report in SQL report builder
I have created a project in Microsoft visual studio on the SQL server (tested and working correctly)
I have a SharePoint server (running server 2012)

I want to publish the report using my SharePoint server but keep hitting walls when trying to find out how to set this up.

The SharePoint server is a band new install OS and SharePoint (plus sharepoint req) I have downloaded and installed Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint® Technologies 2010 as advised on one site.

When I try to publish to this server "SHARE1" I am asked for credentials but no matter what I put in it errors

Can someone PLEASE :) help

Thanks

Comment: Note I have activated Report server file Sync in SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Report Server in "SharePoint Integrated mode"?
If not look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ritazh/archive/2012/01/23/install-and-configure-reporting-services-for-sharepoint-2010-integration.aspx?Redirected=true)

If you are then please paste your ULS entry for the failure.